# bootstrap.css and * before a property name

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been using Twitter's Bootstrap package to build a site, and was browsing through the CSS when I came across the following (more or less, cruft redacted for clarity):

```
.btn-primary {
  background-color: #006dcc;
  *background-color: #0044cc;
}
```

Now, I've seen `*` used as part of the selector, both as part of a constructor like `li li * { ... }` and as part of an attribute selector `a [name*=foo]` (and obviously as part of CSS comments `/* */`), but I've never seen this before. Can anybody share any insight as to what it's being used for? I've also seen it in the following (complete) context:

```
button.btn,
input[type="submit"].btn {
  *padding-top: 3px;
  *padding-bottom: 3px;
}
```

where the `*` is in front of two related but distinct properties. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[This](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/csshacks3.shtml)** article should answer your question. It's basically a way 'hacking' CSS selectors to target a certain browser.

Comment: The link should actually be http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/csshacks3.shtml but I found the answer anyway :) Thanks!